# How to overlay text in google maps (javascript)

Tags: google-maps

I have tried to add text above some markers (i.e. location names).
It is easy to add in Android(I have tried), but I don't know how to add text with javascript. Anyone face same problem?

Comment: Where exactly you want to place the text?I assume not inside the info baloon right?

Comment: not inside baloon , just near the markers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the google maps utility library and more specific to [mapLabel](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label).
Inside you will find [this example](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-map-label/examples/maplabel.html).Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't post answers that depend solely on a link.  Your answer should be more "self-contained".