# Displaying State Names on top of polygon in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have added US state boundary polygons on top of google map like in this example http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_states4.htm

Now i want to display state names and roads on top of my colored polygons, is there any google map API to do this? Or is there any way to do this in google map?

**EDIT:**
What exactly i need is this, take a look at this example
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/layer-group.html
In this example there are two layers "Food insecurity layer" and "World borders layer", in this "World borders layer" is on top of "Food insecurity layer". I need to render US state boundary and its Name on top of my polygon layer, is there any way to do this is google maps.

Comment: Cool.  I found a plugin (that somebody wrote): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785086/how-to-overlay-text-in-google-maps-javascript , but I can't get it to work with Google Maps V2.  ready to switch to V3?

Comment: One [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map_whiteBg.html) (using the Google Maps Javascript API v3, not the deprecated and turned off [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)).  Displaying roads on top of the state polygons is going to be problematic (unless you have your own database of roads).  Look at [styled maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), see if that will do what you are looking for.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay , if i use that plugin, then i should hide default text in the google map, is there a way to do that?

Comment: @geocodezip If you can please give me an useful answer else remove the hold and let others to answer.